# How do I set the keyframe rate when recording with AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I need to make every recorded frame a keyframe, but with `AVCaptureSession` I can only use a few presets. `AVAssetWriter` should be able to do what I need but how do I connect it with the capture session?

Comment: you want to record say, 20 frames per second opposed to a presumed 30?

Comment: @Rob I want to record 30 frames / second, but every one of those frames would be keyframes.

Comment: here are some video frame durations: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDevice_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_4

still looking for information on key frames

Comment: @Dimitri no, unfortunately

Comment: I'm trying to do the same and stumbled upon this AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey in AV. If set to 1 it means only Keyframes. Apple has some example code: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110 but I didn't find the time to try it yet. Another post on here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296642/avassetwriter-how-to-create-mov-video-with-no-compression