# How can I lower the bitrate of a given resolution with AV Foundation Framework?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-encoding, bitrate

I can easily record using the video settings presets, but if I want to adjust the bitrate of a given resolution, I can't find how to do that via their documentation. I'm assuming I need to use a lower level api, but didn't see anything that jumped out at me in the core video framework.

Comment: by bit rate, do you mean frames per second ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly with the presets. However, if you're willing to process every frame and use AVAssetWriter, you can set the bitrate. If you Google around, you'll see lots of posts on this. For example, [AVAssetWriter How to create mov video with no compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296642/avassetwriter-how-to-create-mov-video-with-no-compression)